# Cannot initialize object parameter of type 'Parent' with an expression of type 'Derived'

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm implementing a simple hierarchy: System and Device would be two base classes. A System has Devices. Then I'd have a Network derived from System, which will have Computers. Computer is derived from both System and Device. And finally a Computer has various Devices like CPU, Memory etc. The reason Computer is a Device is because Network is a System and Systems store Devices. The reason Computer is a System is because it stores Devices (CPU, Memory etc.)

Anyway, my implementation so far:

```cpp
class Device {
public:
    explicit Device(unsigned property): property(property) {}
    friend void swap(Device &first, Device &second) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first.property, second.property);
    }
    Device& operator=(Device other) {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Device() = default;

    unsigned property;
};

class System {
public:
    explicit System(const string &name): name(name) {}
    friend void swap(System &first, System &second) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first.name, second.name);
        swap(first.devices, second.devices);
    }
    System& operator=(System other) {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
protected:
    void addDevice(Device b1) {
        devices.push_back(b1);
    }
private:
    vector<Device> devices;
    string name;
};

class Computer: public System, public Device {
public:
    Computer(unsigned property, const string& name): System(name), Device(property) {}

    Computer& addAddress(const string &address) {
        addresses.emplace_back(address);
        return *this;
    }
    Computer& addComponent(Device newDevice) {
        System::addDevice(newDevice); //error
        return *this;
    }
private:
    vector<const string> addresses;
};

class Network: public System {
public:
    Network(const string& name): System(name) {}

    Network& addComputer(Device newComputer) {
        System::addDevice(newComputer); //no error
        return *this;
    }
};

class CPU: public Device {
public:
    CPU(unsigned coreCount, unsigned frequency): Device(coreCount), frequency(frequency) {}
private:
    unsigned frequency;
};
```

Computer's addComponent() has an error because `cannot initialize object parameter of type System with an expression of type Computer`. I'm not entirely sure what that means since that function is called from a Computer class, which is a Device hence it should have access to the parent's addDevice(). The parameter the function has is a Device.

It's also confusing that my Network class, where the function addComputer() uses the same set of instructions has no error.

Could someone explain how my design is flawed?

Comment: _"Could someone explain how my design is flawed?"_ Those `friend` declarations smell a lot.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's the way I understood copy-swap idiom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Comment: You can't have vector of `const string`. If you fix that error, it compiles. I suspect that the message refers to your use of the function.

Comment: looks like the assignment operators are an attempt at getting around the `const string`. They can go because all of the member variables are trivially copyable or support the [Rule of Three or Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). This means you can use the Rule of Zero.

Answer (score 12):

This error message popped up for me today, while I was in the processes of coding the derived class, and in my case the key was that the derived class was--just at that moment--un-instantialble.<sup>1</sup>

As soon as I made enough progress on the derived class for it to be instantiated the errors evaporated.

### Cause

The derived call from which you are typing to invoke the base class is currently un-instantiable.

### Demonstration

Consider the following code which has two inheritance relationships.

```
class Type {
public:
    Type(){}
    virtual ~Type() {}
    virtual void m() = 0;
};

class SubType: public Type {
public:
    SubType(): Type() {}
    virtual ~SubType() {}
    // virtual void m() override; // <== Important code commented out here
};
// void SubType::m() {}           // <== and here


class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void m();
};

class Derived: public Base, public Type {
public:
    Derived(): Base() {}
    virtual ~Derived() override {}
    virtual void m() override;
protected:
    SubType m_troublesome;  // <== Note member here has incomplete type when
                            //     comments are in place
};

void Base::m() {}

void Derived::m() {
    Base::m();              // <== Tricky error message on this line
}
```

Attempt to compile this with

```
$ clang --std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -c test.cc
```

and you receive the feedback

```
test.cc:34:13: error: field type 'SubType' is an abstract class
    SubType m_troublesome;
            ^
test.cc:8:18: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'm' in 'SubType'
    virtual void m() = 0;
                 ^
test.cc:42:11: error: cannot initialize object parameter of type 'Base' with an
      expression of type 'Derived'
    Base::m();
```

If you see all three together you know where to start, but if you are using clang as a linter (as many IDEs do), then you may see the third one (which occurs on the line `Base::m();`, a perfectly valid piece of code in isolation) in a context divorced from the first two.

Instant confusion.

If you remove the comments from the two marked sections of code (making `SubType` complete and thus making it possible to instantiate `Derived`objects), the code compiles cleanly.

#### Two possible lessons here:

- Finish what you start. If I hadn't left the analog of `SubType` half done the situation would never have arisen.
- If the linter is being confusing look at the full error output of the build.

---

<sup>1</sup> In particular I had a member declared with a type in which I hadn't yet overridden an inherited abstract virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `std::vector` of base class instances and save derived instances to it. Use pointers to base class in vector, e.g. `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Device>>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a circular include that caused this error. It was between the child and the parent. For some reason each was including the other, during a refactor.